# What is causing this error :- Restore-SPSite : <nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>

Tags: 2013, administration, central-administration, backup

I want to restore a site collection to my staging environment , and when i typed the following power shell command :-

```
PS H:\> Restore-SPSite http://ggvstg01:12160/discussionforum/GeneralDiscussi
    -Path C:\Users\user\Desktop\Backup\GeneralDiscussion.bak -Force

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing operation "Restore-SPSite" on Target
"http://ggvstg01:12160/discussionforum/GeneralDiscussion".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help
(default is "Y"):y
```

I will get the following error :-

```
**Restore-SPSite : <nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
At line:1 char:1
+ Restore-SPSite http://ggvstg01:12160/discussionforum/GeneralDiscussion
-Pat ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...dletRestoreSite:
   SPCmdletRestoreSite) [Restore-SPSite], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRestoreS
   ite**
```

Comment: Are you restoring it with administrator privileges? Is the site http://ggvstg01:12160/discussionforum/GeneralDiscussion already created?

Comment: yes i am login using a managed account , and the site is already created..

Comment: Are you sure that GeneralDiscussion is a Site Collection nor a SubSite? Is the site collection locked? Can you check the status via powershell? Get-SPSite "yourSite" | select ReadOnly,Readlocked,WriteLocked,LockIssue | ft –autosize

Comment: yes it is a Site collection, and it is not locked since i can access the site collection (empty team site) before the restore .

Comment: What kind of site definition has the site collection stored in the .bak file? Is it also a Team Site as the created via User Interface?

Comment: yes both are team sites usig shrepoint server 2013..

Comment: there may be some solutions or features on the destination that the backup is looking for and can't find.

Comment: can you provide more info about what kind of features u r talking about?

Comment: Please detach and attach the content database.

Answer (score 21):

I got this error when trying to do Restore-SPSite on a SharePoint Farm that **did not match the schema** version of the backed-up Site Collection.

After installing the correct CU to my target environment the Restore-SPSite worked without issues.

Found this in the ULS log to pinpoint the issue :

> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Schema version of backup
>   15.0.4617.1000 does not match current schema version 15.0.4569.1000     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.Restore(String filename, Boolean
>   isADMode, Boolean& readOnlyMode, Boolean& hadWriteLock)

Answer (score 6):

Check in the Event Viewer if there are SQL permission error.

1. Open Event Viewer (click start and search it)
2. Expand Windows Logs and than click Application (in the left side)
3. Check if there are critical error like this
   [image: Error record in Event View]

   with the following details

   SQL Database *DATABASE_NAME* on SQL Server instance *SQL_INSTANCE* not found. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

   Cannot open database *DATABASE_NAME* requested by the login. The login failed.

   Login failed for user *USER_NAME*.

Answer (score 5):

You may already have restored this site before. In that process you also delete the site first, which you can find running the command...

```
>Get-SPDeletedSite
```

You'll see the site (or sites) listed, like this:

```
WebApplicationId   : 009c1289-392b-43a6-8222-146117074738
DatabaseId         : 88efc46f-5a2b-4171-81cb-7577da65bac3
SiteSubscriptionId : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
SiteId             : 86d69f7e-3a9e-4f65-8eba-550d77f93a18
Path               : /sites/collaboration
Scheme             : Http
Url                : http://portal/sites/collaboration
DeletionTime       : 2014-02-21 11:14:18

WebApplicationId   : c73bb367-d329-4ef2-aef7-323ce207d2a9
DatabaseId         : aeb2d6ab-9f9b-493f-aefc-797d4b591f43
SiteSubscriptionId : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
SiteId             : 9d0ed313-0353-4cec-817a-a491a8c5fc26
Path               : /
Scheme             : Http
Url                : http://portal/
DeletionTime       : 2014-02-19 15:27:37
```

Copy the `SiteId` and run

```
Remove-SPDeletedSite –Identity 9d0ed313-0353-4cec-817a-a491a8c5fc26
```

That way you won't have trouble deleting the site upon restore (which is the first thing that happens).

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this error when restoring a site collection from another **farm** that was an older **CU/patch version**.

An optional work around if you don't want to upgrade the other farm:

1. Create a test web application in the newer farm
2. From SQL, restore the original db with the site collection you plan to restore.
3. `Upgrade-SPContentDatabase -ID <id guid>`
4. `Backup-SPSite –Identity 'http://contoso-a.com/' -Path E:\contosobackup.bak`
5. `Restore-SPSite 'http://contoso-b.com/' -Path E:\contosobackup.bak -Force`

Answer (score 3):

This issue may have been resolved. But for someone who might end up with a similar issue in the future:

**If you have recently installed a PU or a CU (March 2013 PU or April 2013 CU) and did not run the config wizard on all the servers, do so.**

It may resolve the error. Ref: http://spreza.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/restore-spsite-force-failed-by.html

Comment: Hi, could you please add the important parts from the link to your answer? In the future if the link fails, people coming to this page may not be able to find the correct solution.

Comment: This scenario is possible if for example you are upgrading your farm to match the source and have forgotten the config wizard step.

Answer (score 2):

Please check your ULS logs and Event Viewer logs to track inner details of this error.

This type of error occurs usually when you have not run the Configuration Wizard after installing CU update. Please ensure you run the Wizard after you have installed the CU update.

This error can also occur if you are using an account to restore SP Site that has insufficient database permission in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

We just had a similar problem that was caused by running out of space on the database server.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an empty DB to old environment.
2. Add the DB to new environment( the DB schema will be updated)
3. Restore you SC to that DB.
4. Optional `Move-SPSite` to other DB and delete the one you used to restore the SC.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that going by restoring the DATABASE instead of the Site Collection using Restore-SPSite, fixes this.
I too had the issue with schema version being higher in the destination environment (development in my case) than what is was in the source environment (production in my case). 
The following message was logged in the ULS:

> Could not deserialize site from D:\Backup\From
>   PROD2013\SiteCollectionBackup.spb . Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException:
>   Schema version of backup 15.0.4841.1000 does not match current schema
>   version 15.0.4859.1003.

Using information from the previous answers in this thread, my workaround was as follows:

1. Remove the existing content database on the destination Web Application (using Central Administration)
2. From SQL, restore the original db with the site collection you plan to restore
3. Add the restored database to the destination Web Application (using Central Administration)

This will automatically upgrade the database to the new schema version, and the restored content should be available immediately on the Web Application. If not, try an IISReset, and open the site again.

Answer (score 0):

We were facing the same issue. Before running the command we need to ensure the following:

- Check if the logged in account has `dbo.owner` permission on the content database.
- Check if the database name and database server name are provided. If they are not provided then the command will select any database at random.

Refer to TechNet article:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748655(v=office.16).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Possibly I see three reasons for this error.

1. **SharePoint Environment** and **patches** "http://centralAdmin:2013/_admin/PatchStatus.aspx"

if the version of the SharePoint is different then it will through the same error code.

2. Check the **database** versions (**schema**) and the **logged-in user** has **permission** for the database (**webapplication content database**) you are trying to restore.
3. Check **all solutions**(wsps) **deployed** to the **webapplication**.

When it tries to restore the site it will also check for the features.  If any of the feature is missing it will throw the same error.

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out of the box. You would have to create remote event receiver (with custom logic) to trigger when file is shared and update permission on the folder to reflect that.

Alternatively have you tried using document set to meet your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After going through the **Event Viewer** I realize it is causing due to the following issue on the database transaction logs.

[image]

Restoring a site has a lot of sql statements running behind the scene and it could create this issue.
To resolve that use one or more of following options:

1. Clear the transaction log
2. Increase the size of the transaction log
3. ****Not recommended for production or UAT**: Update the recovery mode of the database to "Simple". So that it won't record all these SQL statements in log. However, this is only recommended in development environments since it affects database recovery.