# Error in restoring a sharepoint2013 site collection using powershell command

Tags: powershell, administration, sharepoint-server

We have requirement to restore an existing site collection in share point 2013  to a new
site in share point 2013  and for this we have taken back up of the old site collection 
using this power shell command 
`Backup-SPSite -Identity "-Site Url-" -Path “C:\\MoveSiteCollection.bak" -force` 
and we are able to take the back up and to restore it 
 in the new web application, we ran this command `Restore-SPSite -Identity http://.... -Path “C:\\MoveSiteCollection.bak"`  and by using this we were able to restore the sites earlier but now facing issue when trying to restore a site collection. We are getting this  issue 
[image]

(** We have migrated this site from sp2010 t0 sp2013 but after migration we were able to restore this site using power shell command but now we are facing this issue).Please suggest how to resolve this issue.

Comment: What errors you are getting.?

Comment: I have attached an image of the issue

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the account running the cmdlet has adequate SQL permissions and that you are not using SQL Server Express. Check your SP server's eventlog for SQL login errors during your attempt to restore the site. Also, check your SQL logs for errors.

The cause could be related to any number of other issues. See this [related post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76804/what-is-causing-this-error-restore-spsite-nativehr0x80070003-nativehrn) for details.