# Could not deserialize site SP Restore Error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, restore

I am trying to Restore a site collection but it fails with below ULS error.

> Could not deserialize site from P:\backup\InerBackup9-1-2018.bak . System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A transport-level error has occurred

but in Shell it shows below

[image]

I have checked the versions and in development server and production servers
both environments are in same version.

I am confused with `TCP error` and `Directory not found Exception`.

Comment: you would find your answer here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76804/what-is-causing-this-error-restore-spsite-nativehr0x80070003-nativehrn more than likely you havent run Configuration Wizard.

Comment: Thank you for the comment and link.As I have mentioned all the servers are runs on same patches.

Comment: its not about the patch its about running config wizard on the server and then taking the backup

Comment: Dear ali I have run the configuration wizard in the development server.Then I took the backup and tried to restore in production and gets this error.I have a doubt why I am getting TCP error in Log file?

Comment: make sure that your app pool accounts are working properly. Seems like it cant connect. make sure they are running and that the service account is active using the correct password.

Comment: within your SQL server please check to see if there is any error with the log files. You should see quite a few.

Comment: there are many reason can cause the issue , i suggest you can 1. increase the space on the database server . 2. re-backup the site using backup-spsite .3. make sure doing a restore on a new web application . 4. using SQL bakcup and restore .

Comment: Thank you all Issue solved.I run the product configuration wizard again and restore the database from development to Production.